# imeOptions isn't working in an AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, events, handle, android-inputtype, imeoptions

I have a trouble. I'm working with Google Maps Api v2 and I created a basic toolbar like in Google Maps App. There I have an AutoCompleteTextBox on it.

The trouble is when I press the **'DONE'** button (when the screen is in portrait mode), the **actionId==0** and the **KeyEvent==0**, but when I press the labeled action button (when the screen is in landscape mode) it works, but the **DONE** button doesn't work.

In java code implementation I wrote:

```
autoCompleteTextView.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            boolean handled = false;
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                //Log.i("AutoCompleteTextView", "Evento onEditorAction ... ");
                search();
                handled = true;
            }
            Log.i("AutoCompleteTextView", "Evento onEditorAction ... " + actionId);
            return handled;
        }
    });
```

And in the XML layout I used:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/autoText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"        
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/fontColorMenu"
    style="@style/AutoCompleteTextViewAppTheme"
    android:imeActionLabel="Buscar"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:hint="Ingrese ciudad"
    android:inputType="text"/>
```

So I don't know what is wrong, I am working with **targetSdkVersion 22**, with my **Moto G on Android Lollipop** and using **Android Studio 1.1.0**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you are right. Because you are using your own text "Buscar" instead of default "Done". To overcome your issue change EditorAction method code.

```
 public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        boolean handled = false;
        if (actionId == event.ACTION_DOWN) {
              search();
              handled = true;
        }
        return handled;

 }
```